How to differentiate and split `os.environ` into defaults and addons
Is it possible to split os.environ into default environment variables and custom addon variables?
For example, using syntax of sets representing the key/ENV_VAR_NAME:
custom_addon_env_var_keys = set(os.environ.keys()) - set(os.environ.default.keys()) # is there this `os.environ.default` kinda thing?

Is there some kind of os.environ.default to get pure environment variables, after the program has started (that is, exclude all the custom keys I've added since the program started)?
I've tried looking into the source code of os module, the environ is initialized by a function _createenviron, but it's been deleted as soon as the environ been initialized, so it's impossible to re-initialize a environ_2 and do the job, and copying the whole initializing function looks like a dumb way.
The following code gives a brief-view of the expecting behavior. I'm using this for cross file variables, so saving a original copy at start is not what I need:
import os

# I'm using this for cross file variables
# so it is impossible to save a original copy at start
ORIGINAL_ENV_COPY = os.environ.copy()

os.environ["MY_CUSTOM_ENV_KEY"] = "HelloWorld"

# the "ORIGINAL_ENV_COPY" should be a method of getting the original version of "os.environ"
custom_addon_env_var_keys = set(os.environ.keys()) - set(ORIGINAL_ENV_COPY.keys())

print(custom_addon_env_var_keys) # output: {"MY_CUSTOM_ENV_KEY"}

Edit
My apologies not giving enough information in the post:
I have a file named environment.py that will initialize constants, and it will be packed into binary executable along with main.py, here's a part of it:
import os

os.environ["TIMEZONE"] = "Asia/Taipei"

os.environ["PROJECT_NAME"] = "Project name"

os.environ["APP_USER_MODEL_ID"] = f"{os.environ['PROJECT_NAME']}.App.User.Model.Id"

os.environ["SERVER_URL"] = f"https://www.my.server.io/projects/{os.environ['PROJECT_NAME']}"
os.environ["STORAGE_URL"] = f"https://www.my.server.io/projects/{os.environ['PROJECT_NAME']}/Storage"
os.environ["MODULES_URL"] = f"https://www.my.server.io/projects/{os.environ['PROJECT_NAME']}/Modules"

os.environ["USER_AGENT"] = random.choice([
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15"
])

if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
    sys.argv = [arg for arg in sys.argv if not arg.startswith("-")]
    os.environ["EXECUTABLE_ROOT"] = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    os.environ["EXECUTABLE_ROOT"] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.modules["__main__"].__file__))

Why do I need to store variables and constants into os.environ?

This environment.py will be packed into binary executable along with main.py, and therefore, to all other modules, they don't even know there's even a file called environment.py (since now, all that's left is main.exe)
As you can see, some of the variables, e.g. USER_AGENT, EXECUTABLE_ROOT, takes quite some space, if don't store it, there will be alots of duplicated codes.

Finally why do I need to get custom add on env keys
Because I store variables in it, when receiving crash reports, I need debug if the problem is caused by any of them.
Take the USER_AGENT as an example, if one of them is no longer available, I have to know which one is chosen and raised the error, and then remove it from the list, instead of testing them one by one.
And there are a lot of default environment variable keys, which if I send everything in os.environ would be a mess, I only need the variable keys I've added.
Answer (thanks to @zondo)
Save the original os.environ under os using setattr, and in order to prevent re-import overwriting the original save (mentioned by the comment from @wim), I've put a if statement to judge it.
import os

# if this is the first time running
# there won't be a "default_environ" attr
if not hasattr(os, "default_environ"):
    setattr(os, "default_environ", os.environ.copy())

# ... other variables


What do you mean by "cross file variables"? I don't understand why your code at the end doesn't work.

As long as you save the copy of the environment before importing anything else, it seems like it should be fine.

There are no "defaults", only values present on startup that were put there by the parent and values you add yourself over the course of execution. The environment does not track those changes itself. You would have to make a copy of os.environ on start up and track later changes yourself.

On linux, the original environ is in /proc/{pid}/environ. You could parse it.

I do not understand following code gives a brief-view of the expecting behavior what is the difference to expected behavior?

What's wrong with your code shown in question? Put that ORIGINAL_ENV_COPY into a usercustomize or sitecustomize file and you're good to go.

exclude all the custom keys I've added since the program started Save a copy of the environment when the program first starts.  What is the difficulty?

The "cross file variables" part, for example: the name of the project, the executable root path. I'm storing all of them in "os.environ", so in other modules other than "main.py", I can just do "import os" and access them, instead of writing lines of codes, take the "executable root path" as an example, I have to determine whether or not the program is a frozen binary or is still python script, and that would require if-else... up to 4 lines of code, but storing it into "os.environ", I can easily cross file access this variable.

My apologies, it could be more accurate if I said "cross file constants", there will be a "environment.py", and it will only be imported by "main.py", since I will than frozen "main.py" into a binary executable, but leave the rest ".py" so I can still edit the logic, think of "main.py" as a launcher, and so, since "environment.py" as packed along with "main.py" into binary, all the other modules will no longer be able to import it, therefore, I need "cross file constants" to be initialized at start, and later on access them through "os.environ".

Why does that require you to distinguish the original environment from the additions?

In the last part of my edit, when posting crash report, I have to check if the error is caused by one of the variables, for example, out dated API_KEY or a USER_AGENT option that's no longer supported. Posting the whole os.environ obviously gives a lot of default environment variables that I don't need to check on.

Python modules are only ever imported once within the same program instance. It doesn't matter how many different files you have importing something, that first time it's imported is the only time it's run, and everything else reuses it. There are two ways to take advantage of this.
First, the more clean way, which is choose a file to set everything you want. For example, startup.py:
import os

environ = os.environ.copy()
# other settings you want

And then all your other files can use:
import os
import startup

new_vars = set(os.environ) - set(startup.environ)

The second way is really more of a hack, and I don't like it, but if the environ is the only thing you're doing, it would be easier. And that's just this:
import os

os.startup_environ = os.environ.copy()

Again, since the os import will be the same across everything, that variable will be accessible everywhere.

Python modules are only ever imported once within the same program instance is not quite accurate. They're cached in sys.modules. There are several ways the cache can be missed (__name__ == "__main__" or not, dynamic import with __import__ or importlib.import_module, cache invalidation with sys.modules.pop(...), multiprocessing where each worker may import the module indepedently...)

I've edited the post to give more detailed information, since the environment.py will not be available for the other files, the first method won't work, but the third one can solve the problem, thanks.


Is it possible to split os.environ into defaults environment variables and custom addon variables?

No.

Is there some kind of os.environ.default to get pure environment variables? after the program has started?

On linux there is /proc/pid/environ. You can get original environment with something along:
original = dict(tuple(x.split("=", 1)) for x in open(f"/proc/{os.getpid()}/environ").read().split("\x00") if x)

